# What would be the complexity for this relation?

Tags: algorithms, algorithm-analysis, summation

The function:

```
    for (int i=1; i<n²; i++) 
        for (int j=i; j<n; j++)
            print(j)
```

Putting it into a relation, I got:

$C1 + \sum_{i=1}^{n^2}(C2+\sum_{j=i}^n(C3))$

After solving it

$C1+C2n^2+C3n^3-(C3\frac{n^4}2 + C3\frac{n^2}2)+C3n^2$

What I can't figure out is the complexity of this relation.

Solution (from the answer to this post):

$C1 + \sum_{i=1}^{n^2}C2+\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=i}^nC3$

$C1 + C2\sum_{i=1}^{n^2}1+\sum_{i=1}^nC3\sum_{j=i}^n1$

$C1 + C2(n^2-1+1)+\sum_{i=1}^nC3(n-i+1)$

$C1 + C2n^2+\sum_{i=1}^nC3n - \sum_{i=1}^nC3i + \sum_{i=1}^nC3$

$C1 + C2n^2+C3n\sum_{i=1}^n1 - C3\sum_{i=1}^ni + C3\sum_{i=1}^n1$

$C1 + C2n^2+C3n(n-1+1) - C3(\frac{n(n+1)}2) + C3(n-1+1)$

$C1 + C2n^2+C3n^2 - C3(\frac{n^2+n}2) + C3n = O(n^2)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trace what happens with your code rather than simply plugging the limits into the summation formulas. The inner loop won't actually be performed $n^2$ times, since its limit will be reached as soon as $i=n$ in the outer loop.

In other words, your timing function should be $$C_1+\sum_{i=1}^{n^2}C_2+\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=i}^nC_3=O(n^2)$$

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH!

Answer (score 1):

How did you get this factor: $-(C_3 n⁴/2 + C_3 n²/2) + C_3n²$ ?

Considering the formula you showed shouldn't it be something like this:

$C_1 + \sum_{i=1}^{n^2}( C_2 + \sum_{j=1}^{n}(C_3)) = C_1 + n^2*(C_2 + n*C_3) = n^3*C_3 + n^2 * C_2 + C_1$ ? (And with it being in $O(n^3)$)

Edit: I mistook that $i$ in $j=i$ for a $1$. In that case I don't see how that function fits in any $O$ class. The dominating factor ($n^4$) is negative and $O$ is supposed to be an approximation of the number of operations an algorithm performs related to its domain size. With that said, for a large enough $n$, your function becomes negative.

Comment: Oh I see my mistake. I mistook that $i$ in $j=i$ for a $1$. In that case I don't see how that function fits in any $O$ class. The dominating factor ($n^4$) is negative and  $O$ is supposed to be an approximation of the number of operations an algorithm performs related to its domain size. With that said, for a large enough $n$, your function becomes negative.